# How to stop Chrome's “Sign in to Chrome” page from appearing?

Tags: google-chrome

This page opens up by itself what seems like every 10 minutes. If I close it at some point later I could be reading an article and then Chrome opens this page by itself again.  This is infuriatingly annoying.

I do not want to sign in to Chrome.  How do I stop this madness?

[image]

Comment: Can you check which version of Chrome you have? Should be under the 3 dots -> Help -> About Google Chrome

Comment: My Chrome version is 56.0.2924.87

Comment: Does it happen when you are using the browser or only when you open a new tab/window?

Comment: It happens when I'm using the browser.  I could be watching a full screen video and it will intervene and take focus opening a new tab to try to get me to sign in.